# Why won't Javascript beacon/ajax messages send in Chrome & Safari after clicking link

Tags: javascript, ajax, firefox, google-chrome, safari

I'm setting up a usage tracking system for a web page which will send some information back to the server when a user clicks on certain elements the page. I'm sending the information using a beacon rather than traditional ajax because I will be tracking cross domain, but I'm running into an issue in Chrome/Safari when the clicked element is a link.

Here's a simplified version of my code that demonstrates the issue.

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<head>
    <title>Tracking Test</title>
    <meta http-equiv="Content-Type" content="text/html; charset=utf-8" />
</head>
<body>
    <div id="link">
        <a href="">link</a>
    </div>
    <div id="nolink">
        <div>nolink</div>
    </div>

    <script type="text/javascript">
    function track(event){
        var beacon = new Image();
        var location = "http://www.mypage.com/tracking?element=";
        if (event.target.parentNode.id =='link'){
            beacon.src = location + '"link"';
        } else if (event.target.parentNode.id == 'nolink'){
            beacon.src = location + '"nolink"';
        }
    }
    window.addEventListener('click', track, true);
    </script>
</body>
</html>
```

In Firefox, Chrome, and Safari clicking on "nolink" sends the message back to the server as expected. Clicking on "link" sends the message in Firefox, but in Chrome and Safari no message is sent. (Of course nothing works in IE, but I believe that's because of the event listener so I'll address it later).

Is there something else that I need to do to ensure the message is sent before the next page loads?

In case anyone is wondering, there's a django view at the other end of the beacon that looks like this:

```
def listener(request):
    logging.info(request.GET.get("element", "received a message but couldn't find an element"))
    return HttpResponse(status=200)
```

Comment: It's possible that because the default native action of the `<a>` tag will be to obliterate the current page, the browsers might just drop any pending HTTP requests.

Comment: Why you have in the `event.target.parentNode.id = 'nolink'` exactly `=` not `==` ? Is that ok?

Comment: @caligula You're right, that was a typo. The issue exists with it corrected though.

Comment: I can't understand what you want. What does this example have to demonstrate? I see no differences in how it works in FF and Chrome.

Comment: In Firefox the message is received on the server before the page unloads, but in Chrome, there is no message. There isn't even an entry in the server log so I don't think the message was ever sent. I'm trying to figure out why Chrome cancels the message, and how to modify my code so the message will be sent in Chrome and Safari.